# Bigcouch Clustering not Working

Tags: database, couchdb, hierarchical-clustering, bigcouch

I am new to the bigcouch.I have successfully setup bigcouch on two different system which is working perfectly fine.

On first bigcouch i have some dbs which i want to be replicate onto other bigcouch.And i copied all the shards from first bigcouch to other one.And then i used clustering command to make them clustered.

> curl -X PUT db01.yourhostname.com:5986/nodes/bigcouch@db02.yourhostname.com -d {}

its gives the success result.but when i try to create any new database it gives an internal sever error.

My first question,Is this a good way to do clustering after coping shards from one to other.I am not sure if it is a correct way to do it.so can any one tell me how to do it successfully or I am missing something.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that both servers are cluster aware of each other by issuing the following on each.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5984/_membership
```

If that looks ok maybe try ping from one to the other using the FQDN to make sure it's resolvable.  Bigcouch assumes resolvable FQDN by default.

Also, i've seen this happen when you try change the FQDN.  Either in the erlang nodename or the server hostname.  There doesn't seem to be any coping mechanism for that.